# Externalizing where condition in a sql query

Tags: sql, db2

I am using DB2 database.

I have a query like:

```
DELETE FROM MYSCHEMA.MY_TABLE WHERE (PROD LIKE 'AB%' OR PROD LIKE 'CD%' OR PROD LIKE 'EF%');
```

Above query is present in a properties file and I am executing it using a java program.

However, now I want to externalize the where condition.

I have created a new Table PROD_LIKE having a single column PROD_NAME with entries as below:

```
PROD_NAME
------------
AB
CD
EF
------------
```

I want to modify the delete query's where condition such that it uses the entries present in above newly created table.

How can I achieve it ?

DB2 documentation says:

Resolving the problemEven though other databases like SQL Server or Oracle allow the use of database columns for both operands in a "like" comparison, DB2 is more restrictive. When the query database is a DB2 one has to avoid calculations or selects like the above mentioned. There is no way to use a database column as second operand when querying a DB2 and using "like" in a comparison.

What could be the alternative for this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In TSQL I'd probably do this,

```
DELETE 
   T
FROM 
    MYSCHEMA.MY_TABLE T 
    INNER JOIN PROD_NAME P
      ON LEFT(T.PROD,2) = P.PROD_NAME
```

I'm sure the DB2 SQL is similar as I'm sure this is pretty much ANSI SQL.

You could also try a more general to get rid of the hard coded 2

```
DELETE 
   T
FROM 
    MYSCHEMA.MY_TABLE T 
    INNER JOIN PROD_NAME P
      ON LEFT(T.PROD, LEN(P.PROD_NAM)) = P.PROD_NAME
```

I don't see why you need a `like` but yes you can if you want.

```
DELETE 
   T
FROM 
    MYSCHEMA.MY_TABLE T 
    INNER JOIN PROD_NAME P
      ON T.PROD LIKE P.PROD_NAME + '%'
```

Comment: As you can see, I have to use like in the query. Is it possible to use like in the solution you have suggested ?

Comment: Edited the answer. I don't see why you need the like though.

Comment: Getting this error:  Message: A LIKE predicate or POSSTR scalar function is not valid because the first operand is not a string expression or the second operand is not a string.  A LOCATE or POSITION scalar function is not valid because the first operand is not a string or the second operand is not a string expression.

Comment: can you try casting both sides of the like to a character expression?

Comment: Depends on the version of DB2 - my V6R1 instance doesn't support `JOIN`s in a `DELETE` statement.  On the other hand, a `WHERE EXISTS()` that contains the `LIKE` seems to work just fine.